# Group different rows in one by combining strings

Tags: sqlite

I have a data set like this:

```
Column1  Column2
   1       A
   1       B
   1       C
   2       D
   2       E
   2       F
   2       G
   3       H
   3       I
```

and  I would like to merge it into something like this:

```
Column1  Column2
   1       A, B, C
   2       D, E, F, G
   3       H, I
```

Is it possible to do this in SQLite somehow? I though of GROUP BY Column1, but I don't see how I can combine the Column2 data in one string...

Thanks!

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT does not work in android devices or emulator

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
 SELECT Column1, group_concat(Column2) FROM Table GROUP BY Column1
```

group_concat takes an optional second argument (a string) to use as the concatenation separator if you don't want a single ',' character.

Comment: @nida's comment that "GROUP_CONCAT does not work in android devices or emulator" belongs on this answer rather than on the original question. However, I just tried it on a Jelly Bean device (Huawei) and a Lollipop device (Samsung), and it worked fine. So maybe there are some versions of Android where it doesn't work, but I haven't encountered them. Nida can you shed light on that? Can you explain why you think it doesn't work?

Comment: The documentation for version 3.17.0. places `GROUP_CONCAT` in the [list of aggregate functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) available by default. Maybe that was not the case back then.