# recursive CTE to combine values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Please note, this is *not* a duplicate of the questions cited in the comments, as this requires a CTE.

How do you create a recursive **Common Table Expression** which combines grouped data (like `string_agg()` or `group_concat()`)?

For example, I have a simple data set like the following:

```
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ code │ category │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    │ A        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 1    │ B        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 2    │ A        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 3    │ B        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 4    │ B        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 4    │ C        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 4    │ D        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 5    │ B        │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

I would like to generate a result set which combines the categories by group as follows:

```
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ code │ category │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    │ A,B      │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 2    │ A        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 3    │ B        │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 4    │ B,C,D    │
├──────┼──────────┤
│ 5    │ B        │
└──────┴──────────┘
```

I think the answer is probably generic, but I am particularly interested in finding a solution for PostgreSQL, SQLite and, and SQL Server.

Comment: The answer is most certainly not generic or ANSI standard, and you don't need recursive CTE to answer this question.  Tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Base on the sample and result, it look like concat row values... [Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column), [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926162/group-different-rows-in-one-by-combining-strings) and [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: @Anagha No, it’s not a duplicate. I am looking for a solution using a CTE. The other answers don’t.

Answer (score 0):

> With sufficient thrust, pigs fly just fine. However, this is not necessarily a good idea.
>   — [RFC 1925](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1925.txt)

First, get all distinct `code` values.
Then determine the first (smallest) `category` value for each `code`.
Then, in the recursion, get the next-larger `category` value for each `code`.
The result consists of all rows that did the latest step for each `code`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE OinkOink(code, category, combined, step) AS (
  SELECT code,
         (SELECT MIN(MyTable.category)
          FROM MyTable
          WHERE MyTable.code = DistinctCodes.code),
         (SELECT MIN(MyTable.category)
          FROM MyTable
          WHERE MyTable.code = DistinctCodes.code),
         1
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT code
        FROM MyTable) AS DistinctCodes

  UNION ALL

  SELECT code,
         (SELECT MIN(MyTable.category)
          FROM MyTable
          WHERE MyTable.code     = OinkOink.code
            AND MyTable.category > OinkOink.category),
         combined || ',' ||
           (SELECT MIN(MyTable.category)
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE MyTable.code     = OinkOink.code
              AND MyTable.category > OinkOink.category),
         step + 1
  FROM OinkOink
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE MyTable.code     = OinkOink.code
                  AND MyTable.category > OinkOink.category)
)
SELECT code, combined
FROM OinkOink
JOIN (SELECT code,
             MAX(step) AS step
      FROM OinkOink
      GROUP BY code) AS LargestSteps
USING (code, step)
ORDER BY code;
```