# Combine values into string inside recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am using a recursive CTE to essentially navigate down a tree structure of id values. At each iteration of the recursion I would like to have a column that represents a string 'list' of all id values (nodes) that have been visited in the iteration steps so far. At first glance it seems like I would need a group by or aggregate function (like `string_agg()`) to accomplish this, but these are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive CTE. My question seems to be similar to that found here [recursive CTE to combine values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230654/recursive-cte-to-combine-values), but I am hoping for a slightly more straightforward answer that will relate to the data I have added a sample of below. This first table is essentially the top of the tree. There could be one or multiple nodes at the top depending on how many records are in this first table. Here there is just 1 record:

| name_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 15 |

where name_id you could think of as the name of the tree, which is essentially irrelevant to this example since there is only one name_id, and group_id is the top of the tree which will then branch out based on the following table:

| group_id | group_id_member |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 |
| 11 | 15 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 11 | 4 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 10 | 3 |

where the group_id_member is saying that, for example, the group_id from the first table, 15, is a member of the group_id 10 and also 11. So the tree would look like 15 at the top, with a branch down for 10 and another branch for 11. Then off of 10 comes a branch of 4, and off of 11 comes a branch of 3. Then off of 4 comes a branch of 11, and off of 3 comes a branch of 10. Thus, this is an infinite loop since those branches are already in the table.

Essentially, the goal of this recursive query is to return all the branch nodes but not return any of them more than once. This recursive cte will run forever unless we do a check, like checking whether or not the group_id value is already in rpath. To check that, I am wanting to create a column which is a list of all nodes that have gotten hit from current and previous iterations (rpath column), and append to that column at each iteration, making the result table look something like:

| name_id | group_id | group_id_member | iter | rpath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 15 | null | 1 | /15/ |
| 100 | 10 | 15 | 2 | /15/10/11/ |
| 100 | 11 | 15 | 2 | /15/10/11/ |
| 100 | 4 | 10 | 3 | /15/10/11/4/3/ |
| 100 | 3 | 11 | 3 | /15/10/11/4/3/ |
| 100 | 10 | 3 | 4 | /15/10/11/4/3/10/11/ |
| 100 | 11 | 4 | 4 | /15/10/11/4/3/10/11/ |

Where I included the 4th iteration in the table, which shows that the group_id values 10 and 11 are now in the rpath two times since this loop has been fully completed. Ultimately I would want to terminate this recursion at the 3rd iteration since at the 4th, for both group_id values, they appear in the rpath list already.

So my primary question is, what is the best way to create this rpath string inside the recursive part of the cte? See below for code to create the temp tables, and my code which attempts to solve this but is returning an error since I am trying to use string_agg() in the recursive part of the cte which is not allowed. Thanks!

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1
CREATE TABLE #t1 (group_id int, group_id_member int)
INSERT into #t1 VALUES 
   (10,15),
   (11, 15),
   (4, 10), 
   (11, 4),
   (3, 11),
   (10, 3);
if object_id('tempdb..#t2') is not null drop table #t2
CREATE TABLE #t2 (name_id int, group_id int)
INSERT into #t2 VALUES 
   (100, 15)
; with rec as (
select  name_id,
        group_id,
        cast(null as int) as group_id_member,
        1 as iter,
        convert(varchar(128),concat('/', str_agg.agg, '/')) as rpath
    from #t2
    cross apply (select string_agg(group_id, '/') as agg from #t2) as str_agg  -- this does work since it is not in the recursive part of the cte
union all
select  rec.name_id,
        t1.group_id,
        t1.group_id_member,
        iter + 1 as iter,
        convert(varchar(128), concat(rec.rpath, str_agg1.agg1, '/')) as rpath  -- trying to create the string that represents all of the nodes that have been visited
    from #t1 t1
    inner join rec
        on t1.group_id_member = rec.group_id
    cross apply (select string_agg(t1.group_id_member ,'/') as agg1 from #t1 t1 where t1.group_id_member = rec.group_id) str_agg1  -- cross apply to create the string_agg, if this was allowed in recursive cte...
    where rec.rpath not like '%/' + convert(varchar(128), t1.group_id) + '/%'
)
select * from rec order by iter asc
```

Comment: Feels like you might condense all that text into a simpler problem statement with just
- 1. Input  table(s) (you appear to have this?)
- 2.  Output desired (you appear to have this?)
- 3. what you tried (you have this@!)
Short/brief description of your challenge with the code you tried.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lengthy description. I think it helps paint the full picture for anyone who wants to understand exactly what I am trying to accomplish but I am sure I could condense it. Essentially the desired output table I show is all one really needs, with the question being: how can I create that 'rpath' column in my output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At each iteration of the recursion I would like to have a column that represents a string 'list' of all id values (nodes) that have been visited in the iteration steps so far

As I understand your question, you don’t need aggregation here. The recursive query processes iteratively, so you can just accumulate the ids of the visited nodes along the way, using `concat`.

```
with rec as (
    select 
        name_id,
        group_id,
        cast(null as int) as group_id_member,
        1 as iter,
        concat('/', convert(varchar(max), group_id)) as rpath
    from #t2
    union all
    select
        r.name_id,
        t1.group_id,
        t1.group_id_member,
        iter + 1 as iter,
        concat(r.rpath, '/', t1.group_id)
    from #t1 t1
    inner join rec r
        on t1.group_id_member = r.group_id
    where r.rpath not like concat('%/', t1.group_id, '/%')
)
select * from rec order by iter
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AVJEQBl_)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However these results do not for the column 'rpath' as I showed it in the example. What I am hoping to have is all parallel nodes being combined in the rpath variable at each iteration. So I thought of that as aggregating over those parallel nodes.. What you have is just recording the path where the parallel nodes are seperate and have seperate 'rpath' values. I am hoping for them to have the same 'rpath' value. Maybe it was misleading to call it 'rpath', when really it represents a list of all nodes that have been visited.

Comment: @DizzleBeans: if your purpose is to avoid infinite recursion, then this solution does the job. Why do you specifically want this output?

Comment: I guess I was looking for that specific output because it would reduce the size of the return query and make it such that there are no duplicates in the group_id column. As you can see, there are still duplicates in the group_id column from this output, but like you mentioned, after digging into the 'infinite loop' a couple iterations, it does still terminate correctly, just with a couple extra duplicates returned, which I guess will be okay.